# Bootbox creating an overlay

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have an application which stores and displays data from the database...

On the page displaying records i have put a button which when clicked it asks for confirmation(bootstrap modal) and then delete data in the database

I am using bootbox to display the alert box for confirming user action,it is doing just fine and displaying the bootbox but with an overlay and the bootbox buttons are not clickable

Can anyone assist me on how to do this...I am stuck for almost 3hrs now

Comment: Add your code details where you facing problem. Only from text description is hard to what going on there.

Comment: Okay,you want the javascript code or the whole of the html page??

Comment: I am using laravel to code

Comment: <script>bootbox.dialog({
                                                    message: "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Successfully removed this viral suppression...",
                                                    title: "&nbsp;&nbsp;Success message",

                                                });
                                               </script>

Comment: Above code is how i call the bootbox

Comment: And below codes is where i call the jquery,bootstrap and bootbox js files before the closing body tag of the document

Comment: {!! Html::script('/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') !!}
{!! Html::script('/js/bootstrap.min.js') !!}
{!! Html::script('/js/bootbox.min.js') !!}